# Simple arithmetic operation (sum, sub, etc ) with field value in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Let's assume I have collections of documents which have structure like

```
{
   _id: 111, 
   begin: 10/10/12 21:12:34, 
   end: 30/10/12 22:10:35
}
```

and I need to calculate average event duration per collection. To do that I need subtract begin from end during my calculation. Is it possible to do that in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you take a look at the aggregation framework?

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/aggregation/

Comment: Thanks that a good place to start. I using aggregation framework but don't know that they have substracting features. But it sad that arithmetic operations could be used only with numbers, so no chance for datetime?

Comment: would using timestamps (numeric value) be an option for you?  With this you can add, subtract and get averages.